# Python regex compile for multiple string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to implement a pattern below data.

```
-----------------------------------------------
| COLUMN_NAME          | DATA_TYPE            |
-----------------------------------------------
| C460                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C459                 | CLOB                 |
| C458                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C8                   | BLOB                 |
| C60901               | INT                  |
```

I am able to create the `pattern` to select `COLUMN_NAME` where  `CLOB,BLOB`  matches but i want the`COLUMN_NAME` of   `INT` Datatype as well.
In this case i should get `C459,C8,C60901`.

Using below code i am only getting the `C60901`  because i used `|` which is nothing but the `OR` but i want the `COLUMN_Name` for both `CLOB` and `INT` `C459,C8,C60901`

```
#current code
COl_Re=re.compile('(?m)(C\d+ )(?=.+ NUMBER | [C]LOB)')
columns=COl_Re.findall(proc.stdout.read())
```

i have taken help from this document [Regx documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) but i unable to find the solid answer.

Comment: I really don't understand this question. Can you proof read it again?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want to get the values in COLUMN_NAME, where DATA_TYPE is either CLOB or INT. This will give you the list:

```
>>> text="""-----------------------------------------------
| COLUMN_NAME          | DATA_TYPE            |
-----------------------------------------------
| C460                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C459                 | CLOB                 |
| C458                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C8                   | BLOB                 |
| C60901               | INT                  |"""
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(re.compile("\| (\S+)\s*\| (?:CLOB|INT).*"),text)
['C459', 'C60901']
```

This works for me on Python 3.5.2

Comment: Your code gives 0 output .But my code  COl_Re=re.compile('(?m)(C\d+ )(?=.+[I]NT| [CB]LOB)') provides me only the column of int but does not provide the result for BLOB or CLOB .

Comment: Yes i need only the Column name if the datatype match according to my requirement in this case CLOB and INT

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot reproduce your problem. I have veryfied my code again and updated my answer. Which python version are you using?

Comment: i am using python 3.6

Comment: In `python 2.7` this `re.findall(re.compile("\|\s*(\S+)\s*\|\s*(?:[CB]LOB|INT).*"),text)` matches `['C459', 'C8', 'C60901']`

Answer (score 0):

There is a VERBOSE option in re module in Python which I quite like. Code should be self-explanatory (checked under 3.6)

```
import re

data = """
-----------------------------------------------
| COLUMN_NAME          | DATA_TYPE            |
-----------------------------------------------
| C460                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C459                 | CLOB                 |
| C458                 | VARCHAR2             |
| C8                   | BLOB                 |
| C60901               | INT                  |
"""

pattern = """
(C\d+)             # Match a capital C followed by at least one digit
(?:\s*\|\s)        # Non-matching group for \s - whitespace, \| - pipe, \s - whitespace
(?=INT|CLOB|BLOB)  # Positive Lookahead match INT, CLOB or BLOB
"""
match_column = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)
columns = match_column.findall(data)
print(list(columns))
```

That should give you ['C459', 'C8', 'C60901'] which is what you are after. Once you understand you can write: `r'(C\d+)(?:.*(?:INT|CLOB|BLOB))'`. However, there is something to be said for verbosity and specific matching (whitespaces and pipe characters) as abusing `.` can often lead to a regular expression that matches things beyond my wildest dreams.

Really you shouldn't do any of the above! Great hacker Jamie Zawinsky once said:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

If you are able to process the input line by line, I would do it like this:

```
result = []
interesting_columns = ('INT', 'CLOB', 'BLOB')
for line in data:
    fields = line.split()
    if any(col in fields for col in interesting_columns):
        result.append(fields[1])
```